# VSTO: Create Control Binding to current text in WordDocument

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, vsto

for a VSTO-Addin I'm trying to figure out how to bind the text currently selected in a Word-Document, or, as the case may be, the text where cursor is, to the Text-Property of a control.

I know that I could get the text information using the Selection and Range Objects of the Word Object Model. But I figure that a binding is better as I want the TextControl to update when I scroll through the Word Document. Does anyone know how I can create such binding in WPF, possibly someone has a sample code?

Thanks
Marc

Comment: You can't accomplish this with a simple binding. You could hook into a selection changed event and use that to update the control text, perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

The Word object model doesn't implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, so it can't be use in data binding. Or you need to introduce an intermediate layer which can implement this interface and can participate in data bindings. See [How to: Implement Property Change Notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) for more information.

Comment: John, Eugene, thank you, I understand a little.

Comment: However, I noticed there must be some kind of (hardwired?) information. When in word you walk with the cursor from one paragraph to another, the formatting task pane always reflects and highlights what paragraph style ("Standard", "Header 1") the current paragraph has. So I guess there must be some way to always notify the GUI where the cursor currently is. If it can read the paragraph format style it should also be able to Learn the paragraphs's content...

Comment: You can use Windows API functions in addition to the Word object model. And I guess Grammarly uses Windows API functions as well.